# How to add Python interpreter to InteliJ?

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I went to File->Project Structure->SDKs, clicked the + button, chose use/bin/python3.7 and clicked OK, but it seems like the interpreter is still not configured (I still see red lines beneath all code lines and InteliJ keeps suggesting me to configure Python interpreter.

[image]

Comment: Did you restart the IDE?

Comment: @Paul yes, it didn't help.

Comment: If you are using a virtual env for that project, you have to configure intellij to use the python from that venv.

Comment: @leoOrion I don't use venv.

Comment: are the required libraries installed for that python then?

Comment: @leoOrion I don't know, I just pulled the project from git. But even if they aren't, it's not a reason for InteliJ to show me the message: "No Python interpreter configured for the module".

Comment: Screenshot please. I cant help you without see this.

Comment: @leoOrion added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214514/discussion-between-leoorion-and-alon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Go to `File -> Project Structure -> Modules`

2) Remove the module containing the Python files (it won't delete the file)

3) Add a new Module, by setting Python as the Module SDK, and the content root to the already existing location.

I've tested this on IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1 (Ultimate Edition) and it works well.